# PHP - How to combine arrays into one array in while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I have this code which gives me `post_permalink` in a while loop.

```
<?php 
  $value[] = array();
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post()
                $value[] =array(
                    'post_permalink' => get_permalink()
                );

 endwhile; ?>
```

Now the thing is that I'm getting the `links` as

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_permalink] => link ) 
            [1] => Array ( [post_permalink] => link ) 
            [2] => Array ( [post_permalink] => link ) 
            [3] => Array ( [post_permalink] => link ) )
```

The way I want it to be:

```
        Array ( [post_permalink] => link  
                [post_permalink] => link 
                [post_permalink] => link 
                [post_permalink] => link  )
```

i.e: All of the links in one array instead of four subarrays. Please help!

Comment: The result that you say you want has the same index multiple times. I don't think that's actually what you want.

Comment: Your array must have unique keys. There really is no way to get around this.

Comment: Yes I want the same index for every value, if that's possible

Comment: "if that's possible" It's not.

Comment: @user48752 You can't have each array index as `post_permalink` - it's impossible. If you do this you'll have an array containing one element with the value set to the last post permalink in the loop

Comment: @Andy Thanks for you comment. I tried it the way you've mentioned and I got just one element. Maybe I should try some other way

Comment: Before trying a bunch of things, you should probably spend some more time figuring out exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish, and what the result should be to accomplish that.

Comment: @user48752 If you used the exact code in my answer then $values would be a zero indexed array containing permalinks from every post in your Wordpress query

Answer (score 2):

The example of what you want is not possible as array keys are unique.

You probably want something like:

```
$value['post_permalink'][] = get_permalink();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an array the way you want it because each array key must be unique. This will work:

```
$values = array();
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    $values[] = get_permalink();
endwhile;
```

Comment: What does the colon in front of $the_query do? I've never seen this syntax before.

Comment: @max.weller http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php This is the standard loop syntax in Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($value[0] as $k=>$v)
   $result[$k]=$v
```