# PHP - How to append an array into another array with specific key and value?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I don't if it's possible or not but I have two arrays. The array one is something like this:

```
     Array ( [0] => link
             [1] => link
             [2] => link 
             [3] => link
```

I have another array:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 83 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45)
        [1] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 33 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45)
        [2] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 34 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45)
        [3] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 80 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45) )
```

Is it possible to add each of the value of first array into second array with a specific key: For example:

```
Array (     [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 83 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_permalink] => link)
            [1] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 33 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_permalink] => link)
            [2] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 34 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_permalink] => link)
            [3] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 80 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 16:30:45 [post_permalink] => link) )
```

I tried **array_merge** but that made two sub arrays into an array. Is there a way I can achieve the above result. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

My php code for arrays:

```
<?php 
     $postids = array();
     $value = array();
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

     while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 

     $postids[]=$the_query->post; 

     $value[] = get_permalink();

    ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Use `array_push()` You could use a little foreach along the way. It is doable.

Comment: That concept for that foreach is not coming into my mind, making me confuse :P

Comment: Interesting that this was asked not long after [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085749/php-how-to-combine-arrays-into-one-array-in-while-loop)

Comment: Lol yeah that was another silly issue with arrays I had :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add it to the post object before you put it into the `$postids` array:

```
$postids = array();
if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $the_query->post->post_permalink = get_permalink();
        $postids[] = $the_query->post;
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW!! hahah I'm so excited, Thanks a million for that. Such a small thing was not getting into my head